# How do I find a specific character and apply a character style using InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, formatting, character-styles

How do I find all the ®'s and ™'s in a large body of text and apply a superscript character style to each find? Thanks.

Comment: Using what software??? "How" will greatly depend on what you are using to edit text.

Comment: Apologies - Indesign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this workflow, you won't need to manually find anything, it applies automatically:

- You create a Character Style for superscripts.
- You then link that into your Paragraph Style using Grep Styles.
- You can duplicate the Grep Style into multiple Grep Styles for TM, etc.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Fantastic - thank you.

Comment: Just make sure you apply the styles properly. I use this alot for square meters, m2 superscript. Big time saver!